# Export table in PGAdmin

Tags: export, pgadmin

I have a table in my PGADMin and I want to export it into Insert Statements so that I can use it in a backscript.

When I try the backup option I keep getting encoding issues

Answer (score 0):

eg;

```
pg_dump -U postgres -a -t yourtable -d your_DB > test-dump.sql
```

Comment: Or if you need to use PGadmin just set Format = Plain and Encoding = SQL_ASCII and your filename